# OpenCV console application

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management

I got an [example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) of making contours around what it sees in a bitmap picture, and it works great!

But, the code is going to be part of a bigger project using leap motion and I need it to run in a console and just give me the values. I don't need any windows to be opened.

So when I am running the following code, I get _pFirstBlock == pHead. I searched for the error and it seemed to be that my DLL's are not in Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), but they are. I know this because if I delete everything in main(), the application works fine. If I run the application as usual, I get the error at the end of main() - when releasing memory. I put all my code from main() in an empty scope just to validate this, and it crashes with the same error at the end of the scope.

So it clearly has something to do with releasing memory.

What would it be?

Using OpenCV 2413

Full code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 20;
RNG rng(12345);


int main(int, char** argv)
{
    {
        src = imread(argv[1], 1);
        cvtColor(src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

        cout << endl;
        Mat threshold_output;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
        findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
        vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
        vector<Point2f>center(contours.size());
        vector<float>radius(contours.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
            minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i]);
        }
        cout << "Found " << contours.size() << " contours. " << endl;
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
            circle(drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0);


            cout << "Found one at: (" << center[i].x << ", " << center[i].y << ") radius = " << radius[i] << endl;
        }


        drawing.release();
        threshold_output.release();
        src_gray.release();
        src.release();


    } //////////// CRASHES

    return(0);
}
```

[image: error example]

Comment: Check that you're not using debug libs in release mode, or viceversa. That the libs are compiled with the same compiler and same architecture as your project

Comment: They work fine when I am using the normal example which opens up windows. But it crashes when I refuse to open them.

Comment: I wonder if OpenCV is not able to use opengl if it doesn't create windows?

Comment: Never mind, I still get the results, and then it crashes.

Comment: there's an error with the setup of the libraries... the code seems fine... please post you linking options

Comment: I am using pre built libraries and followed the following tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html . What linking options would you like? they are exactly as in the tutorial. The only difference is that when linking libs, they end with 2413d - d for debug.

Comment: Did you try running this code?

Comment: If I add `namedWindow("Contours", 0);` just before the main() ends, everything is good.

Comment: _"Did you try running this code? "_ No, I can't right now, but the error is due to wrong libs setup. _"The only difference is that when linking libs, they end with 2413d"_ That  can be the error... if you run in "Debug" mode with release libraries you get this error

Comment: Yes, but I am running in debug mode.

Comment: Try running it when you've got the time, maybe it works on your machine with your setup.

Comment: If you're running in debug mode with release libraries linked, you get this error. So link debug libraries in debug mode. The code will work with correct setup... this is not a coding issue

Comment: I am sure I am running in Debug mode and the libraries end with "d", so they are built for debug. I reckon that's not the problem, since the error occurs when releasing the memory, somehow.. I still think it's the code. Might be a one line fix.

Comment: Has it got something to do with threads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120690/discussion-between-gamster-katalin-and-miki).